# Editing the FTP Root page

Tags: iis, ftp, windows-server-2000, internet-explorer-7

We have an ancient FTP server that runs Server 2000 and when our users use IE to login they are Presented with the following error:

To view this FTP site in Windows Explorer, click Page, and then click Open FTP Site in Windows Explorer.

The problem is with the upgrade to IE 7 "Page" has been replaced by "View".  Does anyone know a way to get into the default page and edit its settings to update it?

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not an error, it's an informational message.
2. What page are you referring to? FTP sites don't have pages.
3. The message is a function of IE, not the FTP server.

Comment: I understand that that FTP sites do not have pages.  However when users try to access the URL for the FTP site in IE they see the message noted above, along with the informational message that we entered on the messages tab of the FTP Site.  All of this leads me to believe it is indeed a message from the server and not IE.

Comment: The message in IE about viewing the FTP site in Windows Explorer is an IE message and has nothing to do with the actual FTP site. The messages that you have configured on the Messages tab of the FTP site properties have no bearing on the message you're seeing in IE.

Answer (score 0):

The 'page' with the list of files and folders and the message you're referring to is simply generated by Internet Explorer. And as far as I know this message is NOT changable.

And "Page" is actually a toolbar button located on the right just above the webpage area, and was first introduced in Internet Explorer 7. Whilst "View" is one of the dropdown menus from the menubar at the top (just under the URL bar). This is shown in the following screenshot: [Link to the image.](http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/4527/ie8le.png)

(This is actually a screenshot of Internet Explorer 8, but the menubar & toolbar buttons remain in the same place as Internet Explorer 7.

If you can't see the "Page" toolbar button maybe you have customised the toolbar and removed the button?

Answer (score 0):

The informational message you are seeing is simply the "Message of the Day" that you *can* configure on the server.  This is just text.  It is **not** HTML, is not a web page, and has absolutely nothing to do with web pages.  Its presentation is controlled by the FTP client, which in this case is Internet Explorer.  There are two views for FTP in IE.  There is a folder view, and a standard view.